# Foundation - Image leaves container in Ipad/Iphone

Tags: html, css

Images seem to be leaving their respective containers and appearing on top of the text below it. This only happens for mobile devices.

In desktop, even if I zoom to 500%, it won't happen.

I'm using the block-grid tool and the normal grid.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

Code like the following:

```
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Is part of the whole vertical aligning thing. But doesn't seem mobile friendly at all. I made a media query to fix it.